# How to read tags of any event in Lambda (AWS service)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, tags, amazon-cloudtrail

Is it possible to read tags of any event captured by CloudTrail in Lambda function?

Comment: What do you mean by "tags of any event"? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can do anything that is supported by the AWS SDK from within a Lambda function.

That is, you create create a Lambda function that uses [https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/cloudtrail/CloudTrailClient.htm](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/cloudtrail/CloudTrailClient.html)l. Then you can code your Lambda function to perform any supported CloudTrailClient operation.

Of course, you can use other AWS SDK programming languages to build Lambda functions.

In case you are wondering how you can build a Lambda function using AWS SDKs, you can refer to this example. This shows you how to use various AWS APIs to invoke different services from within a Lambda function.

[Creating scheduled events to invoke Lambda functions](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_scheduled_events)